# Match value with range and record an associated value dynamically

Tags: excel

Not really any good at vba, but here is some code I have researched which just does not work. All I am trying to do is compare a value in cell B1 to a row of values in cells L3 to AE3. If a match is found I want the number underneath the match on row L4 to AE4 to be copied and pasted as a value in row one directly above the match. It needs to do this automatically via a change event. The value recorded in the first row is to be retained as a value and when the value in B1 changes a new match is copied to row 1 and so on. All recorded values in row one are retained. B1 changes when a formula on another sheet changes value and is linked to B1, so its the result of a formula linked over. Here's my attempt to code it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Intersect(Target, Range("L3:AE3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 12 To 31 'Columns L3 to AE3
       If Cells(1, "B") = Cells(3, i) Then
       Cells(1, i) = Cells(4,
       Else
       End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To my understanding formulas wont trigger a change event.

Comment: The change event is not trigged by a formula change. There is a Calculate event.

Comment: Thank you JvdV and SJR, tried the worksheet calculate, did nothing, guess the code is wrong. Can anyone help?